# For what value of k does this system equations have infinite solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

For what value of $k$ the system

$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
kx+ay=5 \\ 
ax+ky=k \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$

has infinite solutions?

Honestly, i don't know how to start this problem, i saw that this have something to do with matrices and the determinants, but this is meant to be done without that.

The possible answers are:

$A) $ $-5$ or $5$

$B) \sqrt 5$ or $-\sqrt 5$

$C) -25$ or $25$

$D) 0$

$E)$ Can't be determinated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both the equations have infinite solutions, they must coincide with each other

This gives:

$\frac{k}{a}$ =  $\frac{a}{k}$ =  $\frac{5}{k}$

Considering the equation $\frac{a}{k}$ =  $\frac{5}{k}$ and solving it, $a$ turns out to be $5$.

Considering the equation $\frac{k}{a}$ =  $\frac{a}{k}$ and knowing that $a = 5$ and solving it,  $k^2$ turns out to be 25.

This means $k$ can be $5$ or $-5$.

Hence option $A$ is right.

Answer (score 1):

Write

$$D= \left(%
\begin{array}{cc}
  k &a \\
  a & k \\
\end{array}%
\right) = k^2-a^2$$

Then system has infinite or $0$ solution iff $D=0$. So when $k=a$ or $k=-a$.

Now if it has infite solutions then $$D_x= \left(%
\begin{array}{cc}
  5 &a \\
  k & k \\
\end{array}%
\right) = 5k-ak =0$$
and $$D_y= \left(%
\begin{array}{cc}
  k &5 \\
  a & k \\
\end{array}%
\right) = k^2-5a=0$$

From 1.st one we get $k=0$ or $a=5$.

So if $k=0$ then $a=0$. In this case there is no solutions.

if $k\ne 0$ then $a=5$ so $k=\pm 5$.

Answer (score 1):

Let consider the augmented matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
  k &a&5 \\
  a & k&k \\
\end{bmatrix}\to \begin{bmatrix}
  ak &a^2&5a \\
  ak & k^2&k^2 \\
\end{bmatrix}\to \begin{bmatrix}
  ak &a^2&5a \\
  0 & k^2-a^2&k^2-5a \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then to have infinitely many solution we need

- $k^2-a^2=0$
- $k^2-5a=0$

that is $a^2-5a=0\implies a(a-5)=0$ then check for

- $a=0\implies k=0$ and
- $a=5\implies k=\pm 5$